# How to set label size in mschart?

Tags: vb.net, mschart

this may be easy to achieve it coz I can't find any posts here.  How can I set label size in mschart either in client or server side? Set LabelAutoFitMinFontSize doesn't work in my case. I'm using webform and heres my graph,

[image]

I need to increase font size for x axis and value labels. Thanks.

Comment: So you are using WebForms? and you do want to change the fontSize of some/all/specific labels? pls add some more details!

Comment: yes, I'm using webforms and I would like to increase the font size for the labels.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this code on a sample chart of mine and it did work.

```
Chart1.Series(0).IsValueShownAsLabel = True
Chart1.Series(0).Font = New Font("Times", 30)  ' will change value label font
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 28)  ' will change x-axis label font style
```